# calculated column missing in designer workflow dropdown

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow, calculated-column, updatelistitems

I have a calculated column in a list and I want to update that column value from SharePoint designer workflow but when I am trying to update the field in workflow, calculated column is not showing up in drop-down list of "update item" action.

Can you please assist that why it is not showing up and how I can update that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculated column value updates when you create a new item OR when you change/update the existing item.

You cannot directly update the calculated column from workflow or list forms.

**Solution**: You can change the values in another columns on which the calculated column is dependent. So that when you update the list item/columns, calculated column value will be recalculated automatically based on the formula and values in other columns.